# Specify browser for login

Tags: python, msal

I am writing a python script to query something from graph. I am using [MSAL for python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) to get the login and get the token. When using *acquire_token_interactive* the login prompt will redirect to my main browser. But I need to use a different browser for multiple reasons.

Is there a way to tell the script for example to use a specific browser or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found in the [code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/d7331f26c634240c3b1d1eeabeebc2b963c2597c/msal/oauth2cli/authcode.py#L68) that MSAL is using webbrowser. You can set the environment variable BROWSER and then MSAL will use that browser.

For example for edge:

```py
import os
os.environ["BROWSER"] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

Did not found a way to pass the browser name as parameter to any MSAL function.

Answer (score 1):

Except changing your default browser, there's a library called `webbrowser` which would allow you to do this. In order for this to work, you'd have to find the path of your browser executable, and then use Python's subprocess module to execute the command. By the way this does have fallback if the browser path is incorrect)

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser

def open_url_in_specific_browser(url, browser_path=None):
    if browser_path:
        try:
            subprocess.Popen([browser_path, url])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening browser: {e}")
            # Fallback to default browser if specified browser fails to open
            webbrowser.open(url)
    else:
        # Open in the system's default browser if no specific browser is specified
        webbrowser.open(url)

# Example usage
url = "https://example.com"
# Specify the full path to the browser executable you want to use
browser_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
open_url_in_specific_browser(url, browser_path)
```

Comment: I did not found a way to get the url to pass. But the hint for using webbrowser helped me and I digged in the MSAL code and found that they are using webbrowser too. See my answer.